# Python Appengine run certain code before following app.yaml

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have an Appengine application running well, however, there is some code which I want to run for every single request but I don't want to add it to the top of every single Python file (this is messy, and it takes too long). Is there any way of telling app.yaml to run one python file, then another?

Eg;

```
#run this;
- url: .*
script: everyrequest.app

#Now run this;

- url: /mypage/.*
script: myscript.app
```

Is this possible? Or will I just have to add the code to all my Python files?

Answer (score 1):

You can use appengine_config.py, which runs for every new instance or use the init of the request_handler like webapp2:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def __init__(self, request, response):

        super(MainHandler, self).__init__(request, response)                                       

        .... your code here ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `appengine_config.py` this is documented and is always run before any of your code is run.  This is an ideal place to set up paths, define environment variables that are not suitable for app.yaml , setting up multitenancy namespaces etc....

See docs https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig?hl=en